# error: request for member '..' in 'this', which is of non-class type '--* const'

Tags: c++

My first ever question here. Please excuse me, I have just entered into C++ and was starting up with DS. STACK!!!

My code: I think

```
    using namespace std;
    typedef char stackElement;

    class Stack
    {
    public:
        stackElement *contents;   //dynamically allocated: as we do not know what would be the size of our array.
        int top, maxSize;               // current Top index in the array

                //max size of the array; we need it to know if the array is full

    Stack(int maxSize)
    {

        contents = new stackElement(maxSize);
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        if(contents == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Insufficient memory";
            exit(1);

        }

        top = -1;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {
        delete [] contents;
        contents = NULL;
        maxSize = 0;
        top = -1;

    }

    bool isEmpty()const
    {

        return top < 0;
    }
    bool isFull() const
    {

        return top == maxSize - 1;
    }


    void push(stackElement element)
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            cout<<"STACK IS ALREADY FULL";
            exit(1);
        }
        top = top + 1;
        contents[top] = element;
    }


};

int main()
{

    cout<<"STACK IMPLEMENTATION";
    int i = 1;
    Stack s1(i);


    s1.push('a');
    s1.push('1');
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: request for member 'maxSize' in 'this', which is of non-class type 'Stack* const'
```

Comment: You're ignoring the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Hint 1: What happens if you copy-construct a `Stack`? Hint 2: Shallow pointer copies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If at all, you'd have to write `this->maxSize = maxSize;`, since `this` is a *pointer*.

But better not to write that at all and instead use the constructor-initializer list:

```
  explicit Stack(int m)
  : contents(new stackElement[m]), top(-1), maxSize(m)
  {
      // nothing else to do
  }
```

I also added `explicit` so you don't accidentally convert `5` into a `Stack`.

You also wrote the array initialization wrong.

Also, you don't need to check that `contents` is not null: When `new` fails, it exits with an exception, it does *not* return a null pointer. (That behaviour would make no sense when you think in terms of objects.)

It is crucial to note that you have at most **one** naked `new`-expression in your constructor. Anything else is an exception-safety disaster, and a sign that you need to refactor and use single-responsibility resource-managing classes.

---

The destructor should just be:  `~Stack() { delete [] contents; }` Everything else is pointless waste.

---

Imagine you had to **pay** for every line of code you write. Be patient, lose the source, think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped a lot
But the constructor-initializer list used would not allow me to the checking for contents == NULL

Comment: @user1103817: As I tried to explain, checking for null *makes no sense at all*.

Comment: ohh...yes. Just developing the habit of checking everything. Should stop doing this by the time I reach a decent level. Thanks!!

Comment: @user1103817: Slavish cargo-cult behaviour will **not** make you a good programmer. You have to *understand* why you do what you do. Understanding allocation and construction in C++ is a deep and important topic, but for now just think about why it cannot possibly make sense to ask whether the result of a `new` expression is null.

Comment: right, I think i got that. New would take care of what  i wanted. If new would fail, i will have an exception. so makes no sense

Comment: @Roger: Yes, indeed. The purpose of `new` is to allocate memory *and construct the object*. If either of those fail, there is no object, and so you cannot possibly have a pointer; and indeed there will be an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
 this->maxSize = maxSize;
```

instead of

```
 this.maxSize = maxSize;
```

The `this` is a pointer type, not a reference type

Answer (score 1):

`this->maxSize` instead of `this.maxSize`