# Calling a function on the this keyword

Tags: c++, function, this

So in my header file I have these two variables declared as private

```
private:

    char* data;

    int len;
```

and give this to access it

```
int length() const { return len; }
```

Then in my cpp file I am trying to override the operators in string implementation like this:

```
bool MyString::operator>(const MyString& string)
 {
    //Compare the lengths of each string
    if((this.length()) > (string.length())){
        return 0;
    }
    //The given string is shorter
    return -1;
 }
```

when I compile this I get this error:

> mystring.cpp:263:14: error: request for member ‘length’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘MyString* const’

From what I can tell by trying to call the `.length()` on the this is trying to access a variable on the this pointer which is causing a problem, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547486/error-request-for-member-in-this-which-is-of-non-class-type-const).

That's fine because I can do this instead:

```
 bool MyString::operator>(const MyString& string)
 {
    //Compare the lengths of each string
    if((this->len) > (string.length())){
        return 0;
    }
    //The given string is shorter
    return -1;
 }
```

which compiles fine but now I'm wondering how do you call a function on a this pointer. I thought that because it was a pointer I would have to dereference it first so I tried this:

```
bool MyString::operator>=(const MyString& string)
 {
     //Compare the lengths of each string
     if((*(this).length()) >= (string.length())){
         return 0;
     }
     //The given string is shorter but not equal
     return -1;
 }
```

But again I got this error:

> mystring.cpp:273:17: error: request for member ‘length’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘MyString* const’

It seems like this should have worked fine as I would have dereferenced the pointer into the object it pointed to which does indeed have that method but I seem to be missing something. How would I go about calling a function defined in my class on the `this` pointer? And is there some functional reason why the way I described above does not work?

Comment: `this->length()`. Or just `length()`.

Comment: `(*this).length` would also work, although it's more verbose than `->`. Unfortunately your `*(this).length` is parsed as `*(this.length)` which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that the operator return type is bool, so the valid return values are 'true' and 'false'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if((this.length()) > (string.length())){
```

This should be

```
if((this->length()) > (string.length())){
```

as `this` is a pointer.Basically `this` is just a pointer referring to the object on which member function is called. So, you have to use `->` for all reference to members of that class.

One more advice stop using variable names which are standard keywords. like `string` in your case. Had you included std namespace you would have got the reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below:

```
(*this).length()
```

Comment: That's a very roundabout way of saying `this->length();` or just `length();` .